# How can I use global variables from functions between modules in python?

Tags: python, import, scope

file1.py: (I declare a variable x in function)

```
def function1():
   global x
   x = 10
```

main.py: (I try to use x variable, because I supposed that it is in global scope)

```
from file1 import *
print(x)
function(1)
```

and the problem is that i cannot use the variable

I want to use the variable

Comment: would you want to have it in a function? How about outside a function?

Comment: Also I'm not sure what this last line in your code `function(1)` does.

Comment: Best you can do is declare `x` as a member of a class and instantiate it that way.

Answer (score 1):

The variable assignment in `file1.py` is inside a function. When you import `file1.py`, the function code is only compiled, not executed. Therefore variable `x` is not assigned, and it does not exist, unless you explicitly run `function1` in `file1.py`.

If you change `file1.py` to

```py
def function1():
   global x
   x = 10


function1()
```

then variable `x` will exist in `file1.py` and `from file1 import *` will introduce `x` and `function1` into the namespace of `main.py`.

Note: although in this way your code will work, personally I wouldn't suggest this way, since it may make your code hard to read.
Instead, I think putting the assignment of `x` in the top level of `file1.py` would be better.

Comment: Also using  import * is not advisable practice as it can lead to name conflicts in larger code bases. Better just to import the module and then use for example **file1.x**

Answer (score 0):

I think the focus of OP's question is how to access a variable in a module from another module. If you insist on leaving your global variable in a function, Terence's answer should suffice. Otherwise, you can do this
In **file1.py**:

```
global x
x = 10
```

and then import from your **main.py**:

```
from file1 import x
print(x)
```

Answer (score -1):

The thing is probably that you haven't declared a variable in the first place. When using global vars in funds, they are not yet declared. They must be declared in the outer scope of a function. If you do in file1:

```
def function1():
  global x
  x = 10


x = 0
```

or declare it any other way, you will be able to use this variable in other files

Comment: This is just wrong.  For one thing, assigning to a global variable at the top-level in a file is not a declaration.  It's an assignment.  But more to the point, look at the way OP is importing.  This will not work when imported that way (in fact, nothing will).